# Python - Invert list order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to invert list order without changing the values.
The original list is the following:

```
[15, 15, 10, 8, 73, 1]
```

While the resulting expecting list is:

```
[10, 8, 15, 15, 1, 73]
```

The example has been taken from a real data handling problem from a more complex pandas data frame.
I proposed a list problem only to simplify the issue. So, it can also be a pandas function.

Comment: What do you mean by "invert order"? Maybe this is just me, but I have no idea what the logic of the function from list1 to list2 is. Or are you swapping elements two-by-two starting at the end of the list?

Comment: As you can see from the above example, 73, which is the maximum value is taking place to 1 at the end of the list, because 73 is the max value, while 1 is the minimum of the list. So, at the same time, one is taking place to 73. 15 is taking the place of 8, and vice versa, because they are respectively the second and the 4th items of the ordered list. Ten stays ten because it is the 3rd place and it's the middle value of the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
zlist = int(len(list)/2)
for i in range(0, zlist):
    a, b = list.index(sorted(list, reverse=True)[i]), list.index(sorted(list,reverse=False)[i])
    list[b], list[a] = list[a], list[b]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work where one or more pairs in the list.